# If I use ASP.NET identity, am I stuck with EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I've recently started learning ASP.NET, and after some reading, I've decided to try identity for authenticating users. I've read several articles about customizing the model, like implementing my own UserStore class to provide persistence if I wanted to store auth information elsewhere.

But I like classic SQL DB, what I don't like is Entity Framework code first approach (I don't know EF, I use LINQ to SQL for my ORM). Am I stuck with it? UserManager needs a IdentityDBContext, which is an EF context class, isn't it?

Am I supposed to:

1)Create a new Database for rest of my application logic, use LINQ for ORM - seems possible, but not like the RIGHT way to solve this

2)Put the rest of records into same database, create LINQcontext for them, and have effectively 2 contexts, each with half of classes - this seems kinda crazy

3)Stop being lazy, learn EF, add additional DBset properties into
ApplicationDBContext and have 1 context for everything. But what if for example, I already have a database populated with users from whatever, and need to develop application for that? That seems like a Database first approach, and what then?

What should I do? Or is there other option?

I am using webforms (seemed easier to jump into), developing in VS2013.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go with third option. from beginning you might feel uncomfortable but later you will love it. another thing if you interesting more about user credential stuff read this. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx

http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/

Comment: what dont you like about EF?  There are numerous Tutorials and info on using it.  Also you dont have to use Code First approach - you can point at instance off your DB and have EF generate your class objects

Comment: Thank you guys for response. As i said, i didn't want to use EF because I am not familiar with it, and wanted to focus my attention to learning ASP.NET, rather then yet another ORM. How would i go about changing the code first approach of identity then? I understand that my generated User class, would have to implement IUser interface. What then?

Comment: Why would you start with Web Forms for learning ASP.NET? Why not MVC? Entity Framework, for most practical purposes, is supposed to replace LINQ-to-SQL, and is more optimized, in terms of how it is implemented to construct queries.

Comment: WebForms seemed just more... familiar. I'm used to WinForms in desktop apps(I know i know, ancient) and WinForms -> MVC is much bigger step then WinForms->Webforms (at least for me it looked that way).

Comment: While the event model is similar, you should honestly rely less on server controls and distinguish client vs server-side functionality between Views(HTML/JS) and Controllers/ViewModels, as prescribed in MVC. Simply because it's familiar doesn't mean it is how the modern web should flow.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a separate context for authentication. It helps separate concerns. It makes it more difficult if you want to link business entities to user accounts though.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely not required to use EF.

You should read [this article](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) for more information on how to implement your own data persistence mechanisms.